# Grammatik von »es« in »es auf etw/jmdn absehen«

Tags: grammar, expletiva

*Es* kann in Deutsch viele Funktionen erfüllen – »echtes« Pronomen, Dummy-Pronomen, Grammatikvehikel (Expletivum).

Nun bin ich in einem Buch auf einen Satz ähnlich dem folgenden gestoßen:

> ..., weshalb es der Hund auf ihn abgesehen hatte.

Ich habe überlegt, wo das *es* noch stehen kann und dabei kamen dann Fragen auf.

Rein strukturell sieht das *es* im Hauptsatz wie ein Akkusativobjekt aus.

> Ich habe es auf etwas abgesehen.

Es ist jedoch nicht vorfeldfähig.

> *Es habe ich auf etwas abgesehen... nein.

Ganz fest ist die Position aber auch wieder nicht.

> ..., weshalb er es auf etwas abgesehen hatte.
>   ..., weshalb es der Mann auf etwas abgesehen hatte.

Hier hat *es* schon Konstituentencharakter.

Ein anderes Beispiel, dass mir eingefallen ist, ist *es leid sein.*

Meine Fragen sind nun:

- Wie wird dieses *es* grammatisch eingeordnet?
- Ist es integraler Teil des Prädikats?
- Warum steht es dann nicht hinten und warum muss ein unbetontes Subjetpronomen davor stehen?

Comment: im Vorfeld müsste es konsequent "Das" heißen, "Die Tat hat der Täter auf das Opfer abgesehen"

Answer (score 2):

Canoo nennt es ein [formales Objekt](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-es.html#Anchor-es-14210).

Ich sehe keinen Grund, warum es integraler Teil des Prädikats sein sollte; ich würde es eher als integralen Teil des Ausdrucks bezeichnen. Das Verb regiert ja immer über die notwendigen Ergänzungen, aber damit sind sie nicht auch gleich Teil des Prädikats. Aber vielleicht ist diese Klassifizierung sowieso weitestgehend Geschmackssache.

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl muss "es" hier nicht vorne stehen; die Reihenfolge

```
..., weshalb der Hund es auf ihn abgesehen hatte.
..., weshalb der Mann es auf etwas abgesehen hatte.
```

ist auch möglich. Wie immer bei Änderung der Reihenfolge ist der betonte Aspekt dann unterschiedlich. Und es ist ja nichts Neues, dass in der natürlichen Reihenfolge bekannte Informationen ("es") vor unbekannten Informationen stehen.

Comment: Ja, das ist auch möglich aber "... weshalb, es er auf etwas abgesehen hat." eben nicht. Das finde ich merkwürdig. Formales Objekt finde ich wie gesagt fragwürdig da "es" keinen Satzgliedcharakter hat.

Comment: Na ja, bei "er es" sind beide Teile Pronomen, also beide bekannt, also gilt "Nominativ vor Akkusativ". Soweit noch alles nach den Regeln. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie du "Satzgliedcharakter" definierst, aber nach den bisherigen Beispielen verhält sich dieses (inhaltsleere) "es" genau wie ein Akkusativ-Objekt, davon abgesehen, dass es nicht im Vorfeld stehen kann. Wenn du den Germanisten bei canoo nicht glaubst, kannst du dich ja auch dort beschweren. :-)

Comment: Und die Beobachtungen, dass "es" nicht im Vorfeld stehen kann und dass "es er" nicht geht, kann man auch beide dadurch erklären, dass "es" hier nicht an betonter Position stehen darf, wenn man von der neutralen Wortstellung abweicht. Was für ein inhaltsleeres formales Objekt ja durchaus Sinn ergibt.

Comment: Aber ist nicht "Es fällt mir schwer", "Mir fällt es scher" auch ein neutrales inhaltsleeres Objekt-Es?

Comment: @Emanuel Nein, in diesen Fällen ist es ein inhaltsleeres Subjekt.

Comment: @Toscho... ops, ja stimmt. Das sollte ich eigentlich wissen :)

Comment: Adorno hätte das _es_ sicher noch weiter postponiert - was mit meinem Sprachgefühl übereinstimmen würde: "..., weshalb der Hund auf ihn es abgesehen hatte"